# capturing and processing output from process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to make wrapper in python that will capture output from another python program and later send that output to multiple places like logger and to telnet server but i am stuck at spawning these processes and it's communication
i have already tried using subprocess for running and capturing but i had problem it returned output only when process exited that is not acceptable for infinite loops that most programs are at basic so for example i have these 2 scripts

```
i = 0
running = True
while running:
    print(i)
    sleep(10) #simulate program idling
    if i == 20:
        running = False
    else:
        i += 1

print("Exit reached")
```

---

and second one should be something like this

```
program = "first_script.py"
program.start() #non blocking?

while program.exist:
    print(program.get_output())
    sleep(5)
```

so because it will ask for output every 5 seconds it should get 2 times the same output but also there i am not sure if i shoud think about getting some event listen function that will add every next line to the buffer or something like example above that should receive every time when asked whole output from some internal buffer
My question is what approach should i use and how to use while capturing this output and sending it to another process

Comment: One challenge is getting data in real time. If running in a terminal, a program will emit lines as soon as they are written. But in the background, it will buffer and only send when the buffer is full. On unixy systems, `pexpect` and `pty` modules can be used to trick the program. On Windows there is no good way as far as I know.

Comment: @tdelaney: What do you think of my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50417191/355230)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like this, which uses `subprocess` and at least works on Windows in my testing (and I think it would work on other OSs as well):

```
import subprocess
import sys

# Execute another Python scipt as a separate process and echo its output.
kwargs = dict(stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
              universal_newlines=True)
args = [sys.executable, 'second_script.py']
with subprocess.Popen(args, **kwargs).stdout as output:
    for line in output:
        print(line, end='')  # Process the output...
```

Comment: I don't have a windows machine handy at the moment so this is all just from recall... but its the buffering that is the problem. The example code sleeps to simulate delayed output. I don't think this will show output in real time.

Comment: @tdelaney: Yes, using a pipe will involve the use of buffered output. Probably the only way to process things in close to realtime when there are two process involved would be to use shared memory if it's available in the OS.

Comment: I took this question as being real time display or interaction with the program. `pexpect` would do it on unixy systems by opening a `pty` but that's not an easy thing to do in windows. I've seen implementations that poll and diff the console window, but ... yikes!